# How can I get the byte value in a Map

Tags: java

I would like to get the value of a byte inside a Map object.

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("foo", new byte[]{4});

System.out.println(data.get("foo"));
```

What I'm getting is like this... [B@1a779dce

Please help me.

Comment: that is what the `toString()` implementation for `byte[]` class look like, what is your expectation

Comment: I would like to get the value of the byte which is 4.

Comment: `data.get("foo")` returns a `byte[]` which isn't a `byte`. You will have to specify an index.

Comment: The answer this duplicates isn't an _exact_ duplicate, as that one talks about `int[]` instead of `byte[]`. But the same concept applies. Basically, you _are_ getting back the `byte[]`, but it's not printing as you'd expect.

Comment: data.get("foo") is an Object type.

Comment: So cast it, because you know what its actual type is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are adding `Object` to Map not `byte[]`  so you need to cast it.

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("foo", new byte[]{4,3,1,2});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString((byte[])data.get("foo")));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[4,3,1,2]
```

Comment: Nice... This one's working too. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

As @JigarJoshi mentioned in his comment, that is what the `toString()` implementation for `byte[]` class look like. When you do `System.out.println` on a `byte[]`, the `toString()` method gets called to convert it to a `String` before printing.

If you want to read the individual bytes, you will have to loop through the return value.

```
byte[] ba = (byte[]) data.get("foo");
for (byte b: ba) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: data.get("foo") is an Object type.